# Смена balloonContent метки в objectManager по клику

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

```
        myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
        center: [55.754015, 37.618827],
        zoom: 13
    });

    collections = new ymaps.GeoObjectCollection();

    objectManager = new ymaps.ObjectManager({
        clusterize: true,
        gridSize: 32,
        clusterDisableClickZoom: true
    });

    // Чтобы задать опции одиночным объектам и кластерам,
    // обратимся к дочерним коллекциям ObjectManager.
    objectManager.objects.options.set('preset', 'islands#redDotIcon');
    objectManager.clusters.options.set('preset', 'islands#redClusterIcons');
    myMap.geoObjects.add(objectManager);

    $.ajax({
        url: "/js/points_new.min.js"
    }).done(function (data) {
        if (data) {
            objectManager.add(Cott);
        }
    });

    objectManager.objects.events.add('click', function (e) {
        console.log(e.get('objectId'));
        objectManager.objects.setObjectOptions(e.get('objectId'),
            {balloonContent: '/11111/'});
    });
```

По клику не получается добавить balloonContent. 
Так ошибок нет в консоли, но и в balloonContent не добавляется.

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался, надо так

```
    objectManager.options.set('geoObjectOpenBalloonOnClick', false);
    objectManager.objects.events.add('click', function (e) {
        var objectId = e.get('objectId'),
            object = objectManager.objects.getById(objectId);
                object.properties = {
                    hintContent: object.properties.hintContent,
                    balloonContentHeader: object.properties.balloonContentHeader,
                    balloonContentBody: 'Новый контент'
                   };
                objectManager.objects.balloon.setData(object);
        objectManager.objects.balloon.open(objectId);
    });
```

задать свойства, а потом setData.